# error: "net.inet.ip.fastforwarding" is an unknown key

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, tuning

I've been doing some research into improving performance for OpenVPN and I found out about setting fastforwarding to 1 but when I tried I got the error `error: "net.inet.ip.fastforwarding" is an unknown key` and tried `error: "net.ipv4.ip.fastforwarding" is an unknown key`and wanted to know if I needed to load a module?

This is a CentoOS 6.x 64bit box.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the list of kernel parameters using the command:

```
$ sysctl -a
```

I looked on a CentOS 6.x system along with a Ubuntu 12.04 system and neither had that parameter too.

```
$ sysctl -a | grep forwarding
```

I wonder if it's a BSD only parameter?This forum thread shows it as just being a pfSense & BSD option, [net.inet.ip.fastforwarding performance tweak](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=57723.0)

I haven't found it referenced anywhere except in connection to pfsense. Googling for "net.inet.ip.fastforwarding" only shows BSD related links.

This tutorial, [FreeBSD Tuning and Optimization](https://calomel.org/freebsd_network_tuning.html) also shows it as just a BSD option.

#### net.inet.ip

This entire tree doesn't even exist in Linux, it would appear to be BSD only Kernel Parameters. Here's a post that covers the rest of them, titled: [FreeBSD net.inet.ip Sysctls Explained](http://segfault.in/2010/10/freebsd-net-inet-ip-sysctls-explained/). Linux uses `net.ipv4.inet`.

Comment: `sysctl -a | grep forwarding`

Comment: @RahulPatil - yes I did that and got nothing on those systems.

Answer (score 1):

The `net.inet.ip.fastforwarding` is a *FreeBSD* `sysctl` option, which will enable an [optimization path](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2005-September/008282.html) in the network stack.

It was introduced to the FreeBSD kernel [in 2003](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/de48630dfbd4851b73c7b9665f35c4b6dda706f6#). The fast forwarding path omits some checks for packets being forwarded to an outgoing interface. Non-unicast packets, packets with IP options or packets destined to local IP addresses fall back to the normal processing path.